# Can I delete the old SWF and load the other one at the same time?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using this technique to restart the game. Here is the code:

```
function restart(e:MouseEvent) {
    if (myLoader) {
    removeChild(myLoader)
            myLoader = null
    }
    myLoader = new Loader();                     // create a new instance of the Loader class
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("aaa.swf"); // in this case both SWFs are in the same folder 
    myLoader.load(url);                                     // load the SWF file
    addChild(myLoader); 
}
```

My problem is, that every time when restarting the game, it's less and less smooth-animated, if you know what I mean. I think, that's because the old SWF is still in the frame and slows down new one. Is there a way not only to load new SWF, but at the same time delete the old one? 
I just copied this code, so I can't really tell if this code IS deleting the old SWF. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `myLoader.unload()` before removing it... also use the FlashBuilder profiler to see if the  old instance is still in memory.